# How to prove logic equivalence in Coq?

Tags: math, logic, coq, discrete-mathematics

I want to prove the following logic equivalence in Coq.

(p->q)->(~q->~p)

Here is what I attempted. How can I fix this?

```
Lemma work : (forall p q : Prop, (p->q)->(~q->~p)).
Proof.
intros p q.
intros p_implies_q not_q_implies_not_p.
refine (not_q_implies_not_p).
refine (p_implies_q).
Qed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things that might help.

First, in your second `intros`, the second hypothesis is not `not_q_implies_not_p`, but rather, simply `not_q`. This is because the goal is (after `intros p_implies_q`) `~q -> ~p`, so another invocation of `intros` only brings in the hypothesis of this goal: `~q`, and leaves `~p` as the new goal.

Second, remember that `~p` simply means `p -> False`, which allows us to introduce another hypothesis from the goal of `~p`. This also means that you can use a premise like `~p` to prove `False`, assuming you know that `p` is true.

So your proof should start out something like

```
Lemma work : (forall p q : Prop, (p->q)->(~q->~p)).
Proof.
  intros p q.
  intros p_implies_q not_q.
  intros p_true.
```